# JPQL/HQL. How to query entity A that has a @OneToMany field of Set<B> using filter for Set<B>?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

Imagine i have a table A

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentTask", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    private Set<SubTask> subTasks;
```

table B

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subtasks")
public class SubTask {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    private Boolean actual;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentTask_id",
                referencedColumnName = "id",
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "subtask_task_id_fk"),
                nullable = false)
    private Task parentTask;
```

And a spring repository

```
public interface TaskRepo extends CrudRepository<Task, Long> {

    @Query("select task from Task task left join fetch task.subTasks subs where task.id = :taskId and subs.actual = true")
    Optional<Task> findTaskWithActualSubsOnly(Long taskId);
}
```

So my question is how can i change the method findTaskWithActualSubsOnly so that it returns a task whose subtasks are not fully initialized, but only in accordance with the condition? Is it possible at all, or is there an alternative way?
Performance is a priority in this question so i can't first query for task and then filter its subtasks. Instead of it i should filter subtasks at the database query layer.

Note that at home this query almost works but return null when a task doesn't have subtasks. But at work (another tables but same structure) it doesn't work - it returns a "task" with fully initialized subtasks

Comment: What do you mean by term `not fully initialized`? Means all the subtasks should contain `actual` as `true`?

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri, yea, all the subtasks should contain actual as true, and another subtasks shouldn't be in a Set<Subtask> at all.